# Rails: Is it neccessary to wrap my POST response in a respond_to block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an AJAX form that sends a POST request to the controller. The controller responds in JSON.

Here, `reponse` is JSON:

```
  def send_form_response(response)
    render json: response
  end
```

The above works fine but I keep seeing examples that use `respond_to`. My form still works when I wrap my response in the `respond_to` block.

```
  def send_form_response(response)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: response }
    end
  end
```

Does using `respond_to` give me any benefits? Will anything bad happen if I don't? Or does it make no difference in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*`respond_to`*](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) is used to handle multiple responses in the `controller#action`

> If the client wants HTML in response to this action, just respond as
>   we would have before, but if the client wants XML, return them the
>   list of people in XML format." (Rails determines the desired response
>   format from the HTTP Accept header submitted by the client.)

Say for example, If you want `send_form_response(response)` to respond with `HTML` and `JSON`, then you would do it like this

```
def send_form_response(response)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: response }
  end
end
```

You can do the same with [*`respond_with`*](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_with)

```
respond_to :html, :xml, :json
def send_form_response(response)
  respond_with response
end
```

So, to answer your questions

> Does using respond_to give me any benefits?

Not in your case, where you are requesting only one response

> Will anything bad happen if I don't?

Not in your case, no.

> Does it make no difference in this case?

No, not at all.

Comment: So by that, I assume if I don't want to give the user a choice, I can make do without the `respond_to` block?

Comment: @user3574603 Yes, with only response, with `respond_to` or without it doesn't make any difference.